# Error with Digital Ocean Droplet for Django

Tags: python, django, server, hosting

I have been following along with this tutorial to deploy my django site on Digital Ocean. I have just uploaded all my files and restarted gunicorn. The site is giving my this error:

```
ImportError at / No module named braces.views
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _legacy_get_response
            response = self._get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
        resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in resolve
            for pattern in self.url_patterns: ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in urlconf_module
            return import_module(self.urlconf_name) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module
    __import__(name) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py in __import__
            result = _import(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/django/django_project/django_project/urls.py in <module>
from blog import views ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py in __import__
            result = _import(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/django/django_project/blog/views.py in <module>
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py in __import__
            result = _import(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
```

I have absolutely no clue what the problem could be. I was doing pretty well with figuring out my Django problem while just developing the app but now that I am trying to deploy the site and having to work with live servers I feel like I am starting from square one... Please help!

Comment: are you using gunicorn as a server?

Comment: Yes I believe so, and now I actually have a different problem in the it just says `502 bad gateway` so I can't do anything

Comment: I had this module error once(I've got a droplet on Digital Ocean only). The error was occurring because I wasn't exporting a `django-path variable` to the server. Also, since your server isn't working, it's showing a bad gateway error.

Comment: Do you have a gunicorn initiating file as well? What tutorial are you following? Please give a hyperlink to that. Also, please show some code snippet of your server config file.

Comment: Assuming everything is correct, did you make changes to the views.py file? Did you restart the gunicorn service after making the changes?

Comment: @ShivamSharma Here is a link to the tutorial for django deployment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-CT_l1dnVU&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeA05ZouE4OzDYLHY-XH-Nd&index=11

Comment: @ShivamSharma Where do I find the server config file? I literally just set this all up today and assumed the tutorial would show everything I needed so I have a clue what I'm doing

Comment: @deaspo I didn't make any changes to any files. I setup the DO droplet and upload my project.

Comment: Did you add the app `braces` in the list of installed apps in settings.py? Assuming braces is also an app

Comment: After editing the .py files, restart gunicorn service for the changes to take effect

Comment: @deaspo So I think I had pip installed it when developing locally, but it was never in my installed app in the settings

Comment: @deaspo I did that, thats how I got to the 502 bad gateway error.

Comment: Have you installed `pip install django-braces` on the droplet/server?

Comment: @deaspo I hadn't done that yet, but that fixed the problem thanks.

Comment: Great, all the best.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to run `pip install django-braces` on the server